# Converting Rcpp NumericMatrix for use with Boost Geometry

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp, boost-geometry

I am finding that I am lost without the nice `<as>` and `<wrap>` commands that Rcpp and their related packages provide for conversion between different object types.

I have a matrix of points for which the rows represent points in a two dimensional cartesian space:

```
 pointsMatrix <- matrix(runif(100,-1,1),50,50)
```

I then want to use the [convex_hull algorithm from boost geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/convex_hull.html) to find the convex hull of the points.

However, I am not sure how to convert the `NumericMatrix` into one of the data types that `convex_hull` understands. Further I am not sure how to convert the output from Boost Geometry back into something Rcpp can hand back to R.

```
 #include <Rcpp.h>
 #include <boost/geometry.hpp>
 #include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
 using namespace Rcpp;

 BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOOST_TUPLE_CS(cs::cartesian)

 // [[Rcpp::export]]
 NumericMatrix convexHullRcpp(NumericMatrix pointsMatrix){

     typedef boost::tuple<double, double> point;
     typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point> polygon;

 // Some sort of conversion of pointsMatrix here to pointsMatrixBG//

     polygon hull;
     boost::geometry::convex_hull(pointsMatrixBG, hull);

     //Now to convert hull into something that Rcpp can hand back to R.//

  return hullToR;
 }
```

It looks like boost.tuple may be the best choice

Comment: With the instruction of [Rcpp-extending](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf), maybe you could write one by your self

Comment: I don't know much about Rcpp but I believe that with Boost.Geometry you could do it without any conversion. AFAIU some arbitrary data may be represented as NumericMatrix. You could implement some number of views/proxies wrapping e.g. a reference to NumericMatrix (only to make possible representing the matrix in various ways). Those views could be adapted to various geometry concepts from Boost.Geometry - Polygon, Linestring, etc. Then you could pass it into the arbitrary Boost.Geometry algorithm, more or less like this: bg::convex_hull(view_as_polygon(pointsMatrix), view_as_polygon(hullToR))

Answer (score 5):

Here is a little test.cpp file

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;

typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> Point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<Point, true, true> Polygon; 

namespace Rcpp {
  template <> Polygon as(SEXP pointsMatrixSEXP) {
    NumericMatrix pointsMatrix(pointsMatrixSEXP);
    Polygon pointsMatrixBG;
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsMatrix.nrow(); ++i) {
      double x = pointsMatrix(i,0);
      double y = pointsMatrix(i,1);
      Point p(x,y);
      pointsMatrixBG.outer().push_back(p); 
    }
    return (pointsMatrixBG);
  } 

  template <> SEXP wrap(const Polygon& poly) {
    const std::vector<Point>& points = poly.outer();
    NumericMatrix rmat(points.size(), 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
      const Point& p = points[i];
      rmat(i,0) = p.x();
      rmat(i,1) = p.y();
    }
    return Rcpp::wrap(rmat);
  }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix convexHullRcpp(SEXP pointsMatrixSEXP){

  // Conversion of pointsMatrix here to pointsMatrixBG
  Polygon pointsMatrixBG = as<Polygon>(pointsMatrixSEXP);

  Polygon hull;
  boost::geometry::convex_hull(pointsMatrixBG, hull);

  //Now to convert hull into something that Rcpp can hand back to R.//
  return wrap(hull);
}
```

Then you can test it out in R.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("test.cpp")
points <- c(2.0, 1.3, 2.4, 1.7, 2.8, 1.8, 3.4, 1.2, 3.7, 1.6,3.4, 2.0, 4.1, 3.0, 5.3, 2.6, 5.4, 1.2, 4.9, 0.8, 2.9, 0.7,2.0, 1.3)
points.matrix <- matrix(points, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
> convexHullRcpp(points.matrix)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  2.0  1.3
[2,]  2.4  1.7
[3,]  4.1  3.0
[4,]  5.3  2.6
[5,]  5.4  1.2
[6,]  4.9  0.8
[7,]  2.9  0.7
[8,]  2.0  1.3
```

Comment: Thanks -- nicely done. Do you want to expand it for the Rcpp Gallery?

Comment: I'll try to think about how to generalize it to n-dimensional points and then  submit it to the Rcpp Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

In general, once you go to types not known by R, you need to build your own custom converter functions `as<>()` and `wrap()`.

As noted in the comment, there is an entire vignette devoted to it. There are also examples in packages as well as eg [this article in the Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-as-and-wrap-example/) about custom `as<>()` and `wrap()`. I would start from the Boost Geometry examples in C++ to understand how their datastructures are filled, and then fill them from my C++.   There is no shortcut.  The *No Free Lunch* theorem still holds.

Comment: I have been through the [Rcp Gallery example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-as-and-wrap-example/) and the [Extensions vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf). I think I am right on the doorstep of sorting things out. I have a quick question that may speed me along. Where are the `as` and `wrap` extensions in the [BH](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/index.html) package? I see how you do it in RcppBDT, but I don't see it in [BH](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/index.html).

Comment: I am assuming these must be provided somewhere in `BH`, because, when you run the example where you [replicate the RcppBDT functionality](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-boost-with-bh/). It seems to just work without any need for converting back and forth.

As it turns out many of the data types I need are in `BH` and if I understood the process in that package then rolling my own `as` and `wrap` for the additional few classes I need to use with `boost::geometry` should be straight forward.

Comment: As an aside, do you have any plans to include `boost::geometry` in `BH`? What would need to be done to add it to `BH`?